# Detecting concurrent data modification of document between read and write

Tags: mongodb, database-design, concurrency, nosql

I'm interested in a scenario where a document is fetched from the database, some computations are run based on some external conditions, one of the fields of the document gets updated and then the document gets saved, all in a system that might have concurrent threads accessing the DB.

To make it easier to understand, here's a very simplistic example. Suppose I have the following document:

```
{
   ...
   items_average: 1234,
   last_10_items: [10,2187,2133, ...]
   ...
}
```

Suppose a new item (X) comes in, five things will need to be done:

1. read the document from the DB
2. remove the first (oldest) item in the `last_10_items`
3. add X to the end of the array
4. re-compute the average* and save it in `items_average`.
5. write the document to the DB

** NOTE: the average computation was chosen as a very simple example, but the question should take into account more complex operations based on data existing in the document and on new data (i.e. not something solvable with the `$inc` operator)*

This certainly is something easy to implement in a single-threaded system, but in a concurrent system, if 2 threads would like to follow the above steps, inconsistencies might occur since both will update the `last_10_items` and `items_average` values without considering and/or overwriting the concurrent changes.

So, my question is how can such a scenario be handled? Is there a way to check or react-upon the fact that the underlying document was changed between steps 1 and 5? Is there such a thing as WATCH from redis or 'Concurrent Modification Error' from relational DBs?

Thanks

Comment: This would not happen since writes and reads to single documents do not happen at the same time for one

Comment: I think though, having read your entire question, you mean modifications from another connection from the client which require complex computation cycles between find and update. In this case you would use a version field to prevent out of date data filtering into the database

Comment: Yes, it's the latter case. You mean having a `version` field or `updated_at` field on the document and then use something like `db.foo.update({version=last_known_version}, {...stuff to update...})` and check the result? I think that could work, though it kind of feels a bit hacky. I would've hoped for a MongoDB internal mechanism to better detect concurrent modifications.

Comment: Best to use as version field, here is a good tutorial: http://askasya.com/post/trackversions

Comment: Remember that this is what SQL techs do as well but behind the scenes, they track versions and that is how they detect out of date data, in MongoDBs case you just gotta do yourself

Answer (score 0):

In database system,it uses a memory inspection and roll back scheme which is similar to transactional memory.

Briefly speaking, it simply monitors the share memory parts you specified and do something like compare and swap or load and link or test and set.
Therefore,if any memory content is changed during transaction,it will abort and try again until there is no conflict operation for that shared memory.

For example,GCC implements the following:

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html

```
type __sync_lock_test_and_set (type *ptr, type value, ...)
type __sync_val_compare_and_swap (type *ptr, type oldval type newval, ...)
```

For more info about transactional memory,
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_transactional_memory

Comment: I am not sure if MongoDB makes use of such information, rmember that MongoDB doesn't directly access memory resources. The OS just merely uses the LRU to cache MongoDB index plans and data files